# error lnk2019 unresolved external symbol public __thiscall sfml audio module

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sfml, static-linking

Im having great troubles compiling a simple test project using with SFML.
I have seen many errors similar to the ones Im getting on the internet but everything i tried failed.

I am static linking sfml.

- In the project's properties, I added the path to the SFML headers and  the SFML libraries.
- I have define the SFML_STATIC macro in the preprocessor options of my project.
- I added modules and their dependencies like so :

> sfml-audio-s.lib sfml-audio-s-d.lib sfml-graphics-s.lib
>   sfml-graphics-s-d.lib sfml-window-s.lib sfml-window-s-d.lib
>   sfml-system-s.lib sfml-system-s-d.lib opengl32.lib freetype.lib
>   jpeg.lib winmm.lib flac.lib vorbis.lib vorbisenc.lib vorbisfile.lib
>   ogg.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib
>   advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib
>   odbccp32.lib

- I even added the dll files in my executable folder even though its not necessary when static building.

  here is my code :

  ```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  {
      std::cout << "helloo" << std::endl;
      sf::SoundBuffer buffer;
      if (!buffer.loadFromFile("A4.wav"))
          std::cout << "cant open file" << std::endl;
      sf::Sound sound;
      sound.setBuffer(buffer);
      sound.play();
      _sleep(5000);
      return 42;
  }
  ```

And now here is the errors I get :

```
1>AudioTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall sf::SoundBuffer::~SoundBuffer(void)" (??1SoundBuffer@sf@@QAE@XZ)  referenced in function _wmain
1>AudioTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall sf::Sound::~Sound(void)" (??1Sound@sf@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain
1>AudioTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall sf::Sound::play(void)" (?play@Sound@sf@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _wmain
1>AudioTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall sf::Sound::setBuffer(class sf::SoundBuffer const &)" (?setBuffer@Sound@sf@@QAEXABVSoundBuffer@2@@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>AudioTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall sf::Sound::Sound(void)" (??0Sound@sf@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain
1>AudioTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall sf::SoundBuffer::loadFromFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?loadFromFile@SoundBuffer@sf@@QAE_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>AudioTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall sf::SoundBuffer::SoundBuffer(void)" (??0SoundBuffer@sf@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain
```

additionnal infos :

- Im using visual studio 2010 express.
- I downloaded "SFML 2.3 Visual C++ 10 (2010) - 64-bit".

any help appreciated.

**EDIT** : as I said I tried many things, I have read a **LOT** of stack overflow or  other forums posts, nothing worked... I have been stuck on this for 2 weeks now.
I'd really appreciate some help

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I don't know how VS works but you're doing linking wrong: you should not link against both release and debug libraries at the same time.

Comment: @Hiura thanks a lot for the input, unfortunatelly this didnt change anything to my log output :')